# What does this quote in Don Juan by Lord Byron mean? "Sweet is a legacy, and passing sweet The unexpected death of some old lady"

Tags: meaning, poetry, lord-byron, don-juan

> Sweet is a legacy, and passing sweet The unexpected death of some old lady

I saw this quote in C. S. Lewis's *The Inner Ring* and I'm having trouble figuring out what it means. What does this quote in Don Juan by Lord Byron mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means, "To be left money or property is sweet (pleasant/agreeable/nice) and the unexpected death of an old lady is *extremely* sweet (pleasant/agreeable/nice)."

I'm glad to see the poem continues more even-handedly!

```
Or gentleman of seventy years complete,
     Who've made 'us youth' wait too--too long already
For an estate, or cash, or country seat
```

[ [Stanza CXXV](http://www.faculty.umb.edu/elizabeth_fay/donjuan4.html) ]